# ubuntu 18.04 settings not opening

Tags: 18.04, gnome-control-center

My ubuntu's settings is not opening
       when i click on settings there is a response in the panel showing that settings is opening but after some times it will fade out and the settings wont open.

I uninstalled `gnome-control-center` and reinstalled but no change 
when i run the command in terminal this the following output that i got 
OUTPUT:

```
gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsrpc3.so.0: invalid ELF header
```

please help me to solve this issue

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsrpc3.so.0` library came
from `samba-libs` package (checked on [packages.ubuntu.com search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libmsrpc3.so.0)) so consider to reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-libs
```

Comment: Didn't work for me after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer

sudo systemctl start apt-daily.timer

sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

pgrep apt-get -a

pgrep -a apt-get

2374 apt-get update

ps -f 2374

sudo kill -15 2374

sudo kill -2 2374

sudo kill -9 2374

sudo pkill -9 apt-get

sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, what that answer means? That kill command will likely only work once - in your session. So that answer is misleading...