# Haruna video player (snap) not working - libmsrpc3.so.0 error

Tags: kubuntu, snap, 22.10, video-player, snap-store

I wanted to try the latest [Haruna](https://apps.kde.org/ro/haruna/) player (0.10.3), but it is not available as `apt` installation (that is 0.9.3), and after installing the `snap` version I get this:

`env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/haruna_haruna.desktop /snap/bin/haruna %u /snap/haruna/11/usr/bin/haruna: error while loading shared libraries: libmsrpc3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104183/925128) that I could try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-libs`, but that didn't work.

---

Note after accepting answer:

- the intended version 0.10 was **not** available on snapstore, but only on flathub; the flatpak version 0.10 is not affected by this problem;
- the accepted answer refers to the only snap version available at the moment of the question (0.9), the one affected by the problem

Comment: Do you know for sure this version of the app works with what ever version of Ubuntu you are using? It reads like it does not.

Comment: @David - Indeed now I see that the snapstore has 0.9.1, unlike what I thought. I don't need the snap anyway then, it provides the same version as Ubuntu repos.

Comment: @David - As said, in fact version 0.10 is not available on snapstore (0.9 is but broken). But what do you mean that a snap app could  not be working with a certain Ubuntu version? Aren't snap and flatpak meant to avoid this problem in the first place? I have never seen a snap defined as Linux-version specific. If snap/snapd itself is installable, then all snaps should work. Isn't that so? - And by the way: 0.10 is available on flathub, just like 0.9 is from apt/Ubuntu repos, and both work on ubuntu 22.10. The one that doesn't (0.9 snap) is broken anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed the snapped application is broken. The "missing" library is indeed shipped in the snap, but it's not somewhere in a path that the application will look in.

```bash
$ ls -l /snap/haruna/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsrpc3.so.0 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 145712 Jul 18  2022 /snap/haruna/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libmsrpc3.so.0
```

The publisher needs to modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the `environment` section of their `snapcraft.yaml` to something like this:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/usr/lib/$SNAPCRAFT_ARCH_TRIPLET/:$SNAP/usr/lib/$SNAPCRAFT_ARCH_TRIPLET/samba/`

Alternatively, as a workaround, you can fix it locally, temporarily.

### Download the snap

```bash
$ mkdir ~/harunatemp
$ cd ~/harunatemp
$ snap download haruna --candidate
Fetching snap "haruna"
Fetching assertions for "haruna"
Install the snap with:
   snap ack haruna_11.assert
   snap install haruna_11.snap
```

### Unpack the snap

```bash
$ unsquashfs haruna_11.snap
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 16 processors
2267 inodes (4522 blocks) to write

[===========================|] 6789/6789 100%

created 1971 files
created 280 directories
created 280 symlinks
created 0 devices
created 0 fifos
created 0 sockets
created 16 hardlinks
```

### Modify the snap

I use `nano` but you could use whatever text editor you like.

```bash
$ nano ~/harunasnap/squashfs-root/meta/snap.yaml
```

Change this line:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

To this:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/usr/lib/$SNAPCRAFT_ARCH_TRIPLET/:$SNAP/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/`

**Note:** Be careful to preserve the indentation, yaml is picky.

The CTRL+X to save.

### Repack the snap

```bash
$ snap pack squashfs-root
built: haruna_0.9.1_amd64.snap
```

### Install the snap

```bash
$snap install ./haruna_0.9.1_amd64.snap --dangerous
haruna 0.9.1 installed
```

### Run the snap

```bash
$ snap run haruna
```

Great success!

[image: Haruna screenshot]

Although this doesn't give you the version you want, it hopefully explains to you or anyone else how to bodge fix a snap :D

Comment: Now I've realized that the latest version is not available in snapstore, just flathub.